# deserializing of json using wrapper class in apex

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, wrapper-class, deserialize

I have following type of json

```
{
  "itemsPerPage" : 1,
  "links" : {
    "next" : ""
  },
  "list" : [ {
    "id" : "19623",
    "resources" : {
      "reports" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "followingIn" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET", "POST" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "images" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "activity" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "manager" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "social" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "recognition" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "trendingContent" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "trendingPlaces" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "avatar" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "followers" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "colleagues" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "following" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "members" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "self" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "html" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      },
      "extprops" : {
        "allowed" : [ "GET" ],
        "ref" : ""
      }
    },
    "displayName" : ". ..",
    "jive" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "externalContributor" : false,
      "username" : "",
      "visible" : true
    },
    "name" : {
      "familyName" : "..",
      "formatted" : ". ..",
      "givenName" : "."
    },
    "type" : "person",
    "typeCode" : 3
  } ],
  "startIndex" : 0
}
```

I need to parse "list" node using wrapper class in apex. But as list is a keyword in apex its is giving me exception. how to parse this ? please help.

Answer (score 3):

This tool https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ will handle the naming problem for you.

Or you can use `JSON.deserializeUntyped` that returns nested maps and lists (that can have arbitrarily named keys such as "list") that you can write code that walks through and pulls out the `m.get('list')` value into a valid variable name.